# How to work with plist in several threads

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, plist

I have a simple multithread application with 2 tabs. Each tab is a table view with a number of items, the information about them is saved in plist file with the structure like this:

```
<key>Items</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Bosch KGN36X45</string>
        <key>Price</key>
        <string>18890</string>
        <key>Quantity</key>
        <real>33</real>
    </dict>
```

I need to work with this file in several threads, for example in one thread I can remove the item with the code:

```
- (void)removeItemAtRow:(int)row
{
    [items removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:items forKey:@"Items"];
    [self saveAppFile:plistDict];
}
```

And I can open this item in other view controller to edit:

```
- (void) updateViews
{
    NSDictionary *item = [[[DataController sharedInstance] getItems] objectAtIndex:itemRow];
    NSLog(@"%@", item);
    self.nameLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"Name"];
    self.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ руб.", [item objectForKey:@"Price"]];
    self.quantityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ шт.", [item objectForKey:@"Quantity"]];
}
```

So when in the first thread the item will be deleted - when I edited it in the second thread - it saved this item on the other one, which is now on the other row after the changes with deleting, so I have several problems with the multithreading work with plist. How to make the operations with file save?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a situation where you would gain any benefits of multithreading.  It only serves to unnecessarily complicate things as you've noticed.  Are there any lengthy processes occurring that you didn't include in your example?  If you must use multithreading, it sounds like you will need to notify the edit view controller to update itself after the delete view controller has deleted, thus preventing the edit view controller from constantly re-adding back to the file.  And in so doing, you may even need to refresh the cache stored in getItems of your singleton.

Comment: @Jeremy the main idea of plist is to save the data and to load it after the next start of the application like a simple db. So the cases  are not to loose the information. The operations with this will be to create, edit and delete the info in several threads. And I should update the information on screens in realtime. This is the test task for my future job. I developed the app with dispatch_async but there are several issues which I can't solve.

Comment: @Jeremy it's not a problem to inform the app that the item is deleted but if I have 5 items 1,2,3,4,5 and delete the third after the refresh on the edit view we get the fourth which is now the third, I don't have any unique ID for the items to refresh the item which I need, that's why I can't find a solution for my issue. Any thoughts? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did find a site on the web which describes how to create a unique identifier.  You may find [this blog helpful to you](http://codingcluster.blogspot.com/2012/05/iphonecreate-unique-identifier-udid-for.html).

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks, but I believe that the solution is a little bit simpler for this. Don't know exactly but try to find some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the threads being executed on top of each other, then you should try and have some integer value that they can both access, and then changing it depending on wether or not the plist can be edited. This is generally called a semaphore. I agree partially with Jeremy that there is very little benefit to multithreading in this case:

[General info on semaphores.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)

If you agree and want to use them, just ask and I can provide more detailed explanation/implementation help.

Alternatively, if you ABSOLUTELY must multithread for some reason and don't want to use semaphores, I'd recommend what Jeremy had to say, find an algorithm to make up a unique identifier and keep track of it rather than just using the row number to decide which item is which.

Comment: thanks for your attention to my problem but this is the test task to get job and I can't change it unfortunately. Thanks for semaphores, I'll read about them later, but here I need to simulate the work of this instrument (the app is an Internet shop, where there are two tabs for buyer and admin, buyer can buy and admin edit/delete items, but the process after submit button will executed after some artificial delay to show that threads don't affect each other) can you help me with the algorithm for the identification of the items?